# Check if Windows Phone assembly exists

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, .net-assembly

I have two projects:

- A Windows Phone 8 project
- A C# library project (.dll that I'm using in the WP project, as a reference).

In the last project, I have to check if the code is running on a Windows Phone OS or not. To do that, I'm testing if the assembly *Windows.Phone* exists, like so:

```
Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage, Microsoft.Phone, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...", true);
```

However, this .dll can be used by different projects/applications.

**My questions:**

1. If the Version of the Windows Phone assembly is updating to 8.1.0.0, will the
   previous line crash ? (assembly not correctly loaded ?)
2. Is the PublicKeyToken the same for all Windows.Phone assemblies ?

It would be great if I could find a solution to just test if the class Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage is existing or not, without giving the version and the publicKeyToken of the Assembly.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? It will obviously run on Windows Phone device, it cannot be run anywhere else since it is a Windows Phone Class Library.

If you want to be sure that you are running on an actual device instead of an emulator, check `Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType`.

If the library project is in fact a C# library project, you can actually tell that project during startup that you are running on a device by calling some special method.

Comment: The library project is a classic C# library project, that's why it will not necessarily be run on a Windows Phone device.

Comment: But you cannot reference C# Class Library project in Windows Phone projects. It is impossible.

Comment: My library project has been built for Windows Phone 7. Actually, that's kinda hacky but it works. Indeed, WP7 dlls can be used both by .NET projects, WinPhone projects and Silverlight ones. Magic...

Comment: @ToniPetrina Portable Class Libraries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @AMR User didn't specify that.

Comment: @hico Didn't know that, I'll check it out.